# Django validate form with RangeWidget

Tags: django, forms, postgresql, validation, date-range

I have a form:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = ['name', 'description', 'slot',]

        widgets = {
            'slot': RangeWidget(forms.DateTimeInput()),
            }
```

I am receiving the form in the view:

```
if request.POST:
    form = MyForm(data=request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
```

But the form is never validated as the parameters posted are:

```
name: 'TEST', description : 'fsd', slot_0: '2018/05/15 21:00:00', slot_1: '2018/05/15 21:30:00', submit: 'submit'
```

The form.errors are:

```
Enter a valid date/time.
```

I assumed django would automatically create a tuple of datetime objects for the values posted, but apparently not. How can I validate this form and save it to the database?

Comment: Sorry, wrong question :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your datetime format is incorrect. Try to add the following as `__init__` method of your form to match the format from the post data:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    for field in self.fields['slot'].fields:
        field.input_formats.append("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S")
```

The other solution would be to format data before sending to the server. In this case you can send for example '2018-05-15 21:00:00' which will match the format that already exists in `input_formats` list.